# LINQ count field of selected objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core

I have a **PurchaseOrder** and **OrderItem** class. Inside of a **PurchaseOrder** I have an array of **OrderItem**.

An **OrderItem** has a *ItemName* and a *Quantity*.

Now i want to get the count of the *Quantity* of all **OrderedItems** over all **PurchaseOrders** with a given ItemName.

```
var query = PurchaseOrders.Select(order => from item in order.OrderedItems where itemName == item.ItemName)
```

This is how far i came, but that only returns orders which do have an itemName in their order, which is far from my goal.

How can i achieve that in LINQ?

Comment: `.Count()` can help you

Comment: have you tried `var query = PurchaseOrders.Select(order => from item in order.OrderedItems where itemName == item.ItemName).Count();`

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake in my question. I want to have the count of the field quantity of all items with a given name over all purchaseOrders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get total quantity for only one name use `SelectMany` to get collection of all items from collection of orders.

```
var count = PurchaseOrders
    .SelectMany(order => order.OrderedItems)
    .Where(item => item.ItemName == "name")
    .Sum(item => item.Quantity);
```

With combination of `SelectMany` and `GroupBy` you can build a dictionary where Key is a name of item and Value is a total quantity of items with corresponding name.

```
var quantities = PurchaseOrders
    .SelectMany(order => order.OrderedItems)
    .GroupBy(item => item.ItemName)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Sum(item => item.Quantity));

// Then you can get total quantity for any name
var quantity = quantities.GetValueOrDefault("firstItem");
```

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake in my question. I want to have the count of the field quantity of all items with a given name over all purchaseOrders.

Comment: @Bioaim, use `Sum` to calculate total quantity